# when popbackstack OnResume(), OnCreateView(), nothing is called. But the previous fragment is shown. want to resume fragment what to do?

Tags: android

//fragment is replaced using the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, MessagesListFragment.newInstance(), "List")
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_from_left, 0)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

//when pressed back popbackstack is called like this

````
 if (messageFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                        navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rl_message_top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        messageFragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();```
}
````

Comment: you want to get last fragment to add in stack.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a fragment, `setUserVisibleHint(true)` and then override

```
    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
       // what you want to do
    }
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

in your first fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve these via  getFragmentManager().popBackStack() methods.

Check below doc for more details : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()